# identifier expected error

Tags: java

I keep getting  expected on this line, could you help me please?

```
 System.out.println(a*b);
```

Here is the full code:

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Calculator here.
 * 
 * @author (Aneeqa Rustam) 
 * @version (10/08/2014)
 */
public class Calculator
{
    public static void Calculator (String[] args);

        int a =2000000, b =4000000;
        System.out.println(a*b);
```

Comment: This is Java, not Javascript.

Comment: Remove the `;` at end of line `public static void Calculator (String[] args);` and add a `{`

Comment: You know you are gonna get an `int` overflow doing this multiplication. Right?

Comment: what do you mean? @xgeorgekx

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void Calculator (String[] args);
```

is not valid method definition

change it to

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

 int a =2000000, b =4000000;
 System.out.println(a*b);

}
```

Comment: I changed it thank you. On the same line it still says <identifier> expected, I have no idea what to do, Help?

Comment: post the exact error message with new code in your question